# Pros and cons of paragraph-based writing

Tags: thesis, writing-style, formatting

The ancient masters, such as Euler, wrote in a paragraph-based
  style, where each paragraph was numbered and tried to explain one
  concept in about paragraph-length.

Nowadays, papers seem more structured, with more headings, etc.

Is there any study as to the readability of both styles?<sup>1</sup>

(I started writing a thesis which so far has emerged in
  paragraph-based style. This has worked pretty well for writing, yet
  readability might be an issue. Is writing like this a no-go?)

---

<sup>1</sup> If not, how is your personal experience if you have written both ways?

Comment: Follow the norms of your discipline, if you want to be taken seriously. If everyone else uses sections, subsections and you do not it will only look bad on you.

Comment: @Alexandros: that is a sensible answer, thank you

Comment: @Alexandros Can you please convert this into an answer so that I can vote for it?

Comment: I may misunderstand you ( i don't read Euler), but these two styles are not exclusive. Many researcher use a writing style essentially based on paragraph chunks later organized and connected properly for readability.

Comment: @Greg: Collecting "paragraph chunks" is essentially the work style that emerged. I was unsure how to proceed to produce a good thesis, how much organization and connection was best. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user It is not necessarily a bad writing style. If you try writing support software like Scrivener it very much supports (encourages) you to do it that way. Also, I heard from many Tex/Latex users that they are very outline/paragraph centered writers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most important follow the norms of your discipline.
The paragraph-based writing does not exclude the hierarchical notation of section/subsection, it does complete it. Paragraph is one entity in a hierarchical build document. Each paragraph should have a claim, an analysis or reasoning, and a conclusion. The only difference in the writing of Euler to modern writing is that he numbers each paragraph. This was common in its time. Due to the fact, that a teaching book gets a new version every few years, it makes less sense today. E.g. do you mean the paragraph 45 in the hard book version of 2005 or the paragraph 45 in the soft cover of 2008?

Answer (score 9):

Following the advice by @jakebeal, I am posting my comment as answer.

Follow the norms of your discipline, if you want to be taken seriously. If everyone else uses sections and  subsections and you do not, it will only look bad on you.